# CodeIgniter Template Parser Variable Arrays?

Tags: php, codeigniter, parsing, templates

So, my traditional method is using the template parser class instead of the standard view loading method.  The only trouble with this is that variables can start to get messy after a while if more than one `category` of variables is used.

For example... an array like this:

```
$data = array(
    'THREAD' => array(
        'TITLE' => "Some Cool Title",
        'MESSAGE' => "Hello, world!",
        'AUTHOR' => $author_info //Some Array of author's info
    ),
    'COMMENT_RESULTS' => array(
        array(
            'MESSAGE' => "hello, world!",
            'AUTHOR' => array()
        )
    )
);
```

**View:**

```
<h1>{THREAD:TITLE}</h1> 
<H2>Posted by {THREAD:AUTHOR:USERNAME}

<p>{THREAD:MESSAGE}</p>

<ul>{COMMENT_RESULTS}
     <li>
          {COMMENT:MESSAGE}
          Posted by {COMMENT:AUTHOR:USERNAME}
     </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{TITLE}

Posted by {AUTHOR}

{MESSAGE}

{COMMENT_RESULTS}

      {MESSAGE}
      Posted by {AUTHOR}

{/COMMENT_RESULTS}
```